# Deeplink redirecting to home page after login instead of going to target page in swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

Currently I create a DeepLink to open specific UIViewController based on notification UserInfo data in Swift.

This DeepLink going to specific page if the user is logged in already. In case user is not login, I push them to login page. But, is it possible to make user going to target or destination page after login instead of home page?

e.g.

I push a notification that redirect user to inbox

Current implementation

a. If user logged in
User tap notification -> inboxViewController

b. Is user not logged in
User tap notification -> user login -> home page

My Expectation

a. If user not logged in
User tap notification -> user login -> inboxViewController

Is there any way to realize it ?

---

Comment: Save your destination, post a notification when user logs in and add an observer for that notification.

Comment: do you mean like saving the destination in userdefault?

Comment: @lauwis - Yes that is an option, you could even save it in a variable in some sort of a class you have that takes care of the app state. What Leo Dabus suggested essentially means that whenever you receive such a notification, and you determine that the user is not logged-in, save this notification and present the login screen to the user. Then if the user completes login, then check if the place you saved the notification to has a saved notification. If there is one, then redirect user to the inbox view controller. If the user does not login though, then clear the notification.

Comment: Clearing the saved notification would help in the sense that lets say a notification arrived, you ask the user to login but they don't. They go to the home screen and then later of their own volition they decide to login, then in this case you may not want them to be redirected to the inbox screen. It really depends on your app's functional flows to be honest.

Comment: Also, my suggestion is slightly different from what Leo Dabus wrote, but that is just a modality. The idea is that upon login you need to check for the presence of a saved notification and then take action accordingly.

Comment: No need to persist it to disk. A Singleton would be enough for this considering it doesn’t need to be available next launch

Comment: Thanks @AmanShankarSharma for the solution. Yes there's a possibility user access home page without login. Clearing the saved notification will be implemented then